# How do I disable notification sounds and vibrate in messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger, android-11

I'd like to disable sounds and vibration for messages on Facebook messenger, but leave on sound/vibration for calls and other apps. How can I do this?

Comment: Configure channels in app's notification settings (provided that it uses different channels) to control different types of notofications.

Comment: @IrfanLatif what do you mean by "channels" - I don't see that mentioned in Messenger's notification settings, nor in the android notification settings.

Comment: I don't have Messenger app to guide you precisely, so this may help: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+notification+channels

Answer (score 0):

As of now, notifications for chats and calls in Messenger are grouped and can only be enabled/disabled together.

Your best bet is to contact facebook/messenger and ask them to add the feature, by splitting the notifications into channels, which can then be controlled seperately.

[image: messenger notification channels on android]